# Xcode 7 (7D1014) non - Automatic option in Assistant Editor

Tags: xcode, assistant

How to set Assistant editor to "Automatic"  option?
the option gone. Please help.

[xcode without Automatic option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8nbr.png)

Comment: be a little more communicative: what do u mean?

Comment: I cant change viewports mode to "automatic" anymore. The option were gone from the menu bar (as you can see in the screenshot).